# settings.json environtment variables for python.pythonPath not working between Windows and Linux

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, environment-variables, interpreter, pyenv

How does one get environment variables to work on the same VS Code project while switching between Windows and Linux?

I've created a `PYTHON_INSTALL_LOC` environment variable in Linux and in Windows.

On Linux I have this in my .zshrc: `export PYTHON_INSTALL_LOC=$HOME/.pyenv/versions/3.7.7/bin/python` and hit it with source to refresh.

On Windows I have this set as the value: `C:\Users\username\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.7.7\python.exe`

Per [Manually specify an interpreter - #3](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_manually-specify-an-interpreter), I've set the following in .vscode/settings.json:

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "${env:PYTHON_INSTALL_LOC}",
}
```

Under Windows I can `echo ${env:PYTHON_INSTALL_LOC}` and get the path to python.exe.

On Linux it doesn't work and I get:

> zsh: unrecognized modifier

However, `echo ${PYTHON_INSTALL_LOC}` works as expected.

Note: I've read over 25 pages of various Github issues and SO questions, tried many of them and I still haven't found a solution to get this working between environments.

I'm using Pyenv, which works fine otherwise but, I've tried it with `python -m venv .venv` as well, to see if that route was easier. I've also tried adding both python paths to PATH on both systems, hoping each would be picked up automatically, as the docs suggested but, that didn't seem to work either.

That said, I'd appreciate any direction you can provide. Thanks!